# Leiningen script installing version 1.7.1 instead of version 2.6.1? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, clojure, leiningen

Downloaded and installed lein script per website instructions (to my understanding), but for some reason it's installing as version 1.7.1 even though the script specifies version 2.6.1

I've tried running in /usr/ as well as /usr/local/bin/, both with the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens because lein is installed both manually and through a package manager such as home-brew or apt-get where the system package is very old and being places first on the $PATH so it gets run instead of the one you installed. First thing to check is that your package manager does *not* have leiningen installed (and if so, uninstall or update it)